# Cannot open RAML view in Atom editor

Tags: rest, atom-editor, raml

I installed Atom 1.8.0 and RAML package on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Then I opened the API source code in Atom and just wanted to open the RAML view (I have *.raml file), however I cannot see this package in Packages menu. I reloaded the project in Developer mode, but again the same problem.
In fact I worked with Atom+RAML on another machine (Ubuntu 14.04) and the steps I described above worked fine for me. But I think that I used another version of Atom. Anyway, the question is how to open the RAML view in Atom to be able to test GET and POST requests?

Comment: It would have been helpful to link the package you're talking about. The [raml](https://atom.io/packages/raml) package only provides syntax highlighting and snippets, it does neither have a menu nor any commands to run.

Comment: @idleberg: Thanks. In this case do you know how to test REST APi from Atom? I remember that I was able to open the specific menu for this. I just was opening RAML file and then opened Developer tools, and I was able to test GET and POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume, that you're talking about [atom-raml-preview](https://atom.io/packages/atom-raml-preview) (rather than the [raml](https://atom.io/packages/raml) package), since that's the only one providing a menu and a separate view.

The package is using deprecated APIs and can't be activated in recent Atom versions. In the console, Atom reports this warning:

```
Could not load atom-raml-preview@0.0.1 because it uses deprecated APIs that have been removed.
```

You're only chances are getting in touch with the author to [report the issue](https://github.com/cybertk/atom-raml-preview), or update the package yourself.

**Update**: Apparently, [several issues](https://github.com/cybertk/atom-raml-preview/issues) have been submitted already, the last one from May 2015. This list provides some [detailed info](https://github.com/benogle/deprecation-data/blob/master/output/deprecations-by-package-all.md) on the deprecated API functions used by the package.

Comment: which version of Atom is compatible with this API?

Comment: According to [this blog post](http://blog.atom.io/2015/06/04/deprecated-apis-have-been-removed.html), deprecated APIs have been removed in v0.206.0